# How to change prestashop order listing page?

Tags: html, module, prestashop

I want to add a new module to prestashop back office order page. So can anyone tell me which tpl file to change so that I can simly add a new hook ? I added a hook to controller file, but I can't find a tpl file.

Comment: Did you change the controller file into override directory?

Comment: Yes, but only a controller file, not tpl

Comment: Can you put your code modified in controller?

Comment: Hmm, but I dont understand why u need body of my controller. I got a hook linked with variable and send by smarty, but this is not a problem. I have a problem with find a good one tpl for order list, cause this controller have many tpls and  orders list is linked with order view. I just need a name of tpl (the one who performed when list loading)

Comment: Backoffice order list doesn't use its own template but a standard helper template used to generate lists in `youradminfolder/themes/default/template/helpers/list/list_content.tpl`. Can you explain what exactly are you trying to do with your hook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you want to add something to the order details page then there are several hooks available for the same, you can use any of them.

Some of the hooks are:

HOOK_TAB_SHIP
HOOK_TAB_ORDER
HOOK_CONTENT_SHIP
HOOK_CONTENT_ORDER

To add something to the orders listing page through a module is not possible without overriding a core file. You need to override renderList() of file /controllers/admin/AdminOrdersController.php

Comment: Thanks, I got a one more question, how can I edit the title page in order view( BO), Now i have (order ref, firstname, surname) and I want to change order ref for order id, maybe u know where I can look for this little change?